# Replacing OS's in a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I am running a Linux mint 18.3 and Windows 7 in a dual boot  and I would like to replace the Linux mint with Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Launch your new Ubuntu installation (via USB or other) and erase the Linux Mint partition when you are in the installation process of Ubuntu.

I hope will help you !

Comment: @Nfuture But be careful you will lost your data, don't forget to save it before.